# Django: Tying transactions to HTTP requests

Tags: django, transactions

I have questions about wrapping requests in transactions: 
1. What is the 'Atomic' part about "[Set ATOMIC_REQUESTS to True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests)" in the database settings in Django? 
2. When are locks to the database obtained, and released? 
3. Is the entire database locked, ie. all tables, or is it just some row of a table? In other words what is granularity of the lock? 
4. Do these things matter, depending on which database is being used? 
 Thank you for your input.